# Passing boolean parameter to DAO for close hibernate session. Is it right way to implement?

Tags: java, hibernate, dao

In my application i no need to close the hibernate session for each and every DAO methods. So, Can i set boolean parameter in DAO methods to close Hibernate session?

I am using

- Struts2 & Hibernate. (No Spring)
- ThreadLocaled Hibernate SessionFactory

Comment: You didn't ask a question :-)

Comment: How do you manage transactions? The most common usage pattern is to allocate a Hibernat esession per transaction.

Comment: @ Olaf Hibernate session per http request(ThreadLocaled Hibernate SessionFactory). Right now, Closing hibernate session have been added in the finally block of DAO method.

Comment: @SampathKumar: I don't think this is a good approach. What happens if you whant to perfrom two DAO methods in the same transaction?

Comment: Based on the boolean param I have,  I can commit transaction  as well as close hibernate session.